# sigaction not initialized gcc 7

Tags: c, gcc, structure, sigaction

Let be this C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handle(){
    return;
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = &handle;
    printf("%d\n", action.sa_flags);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) throws a warning:

```
src/flags.c:14:2: warning: ‘action.sa_flags’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("%d\n", action.sa_flags);
```

However, with gcc-5 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11), no warning.

With gcc-7, the `sa_flags` value is really not initialized:

```
(gdb) x action.sa_flags
0x555545a0:    Cannot access memory at address 0x555545a0
```

where with gcc-5, it gets a strange value:

```
(gdb) x action.sa_flags
0x4004a0 <_start>:    0x8949ed31
```

I don't get why:

- with gcc-7, `sa_flags` are not initiliazed to 0.
- with gcc-5, `sa_flags` and the `_start` function have the same address.

Comment: Makes sense that a newer version of compiler gives more/better warnings.

Comment: Uninitialized variables/elements of struct variables in a function have garbage values and trying to use them before setting them to something is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shawn the problem is that the manual (man sigaction) tells nothing about such a behavior.

Comment: `sa_flags and the _start function have the same address.` - the `sa_flags` contains a garbage value that happens to be equal to the address of `_start`. Which kind-of makes sense, probably a leftover from crt0.

Comment: Er... it has nothing to do with `sigaction()`, and everything to do with the C language and [implicit initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization#Implicit_initialization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `struct sigaction action` isn't initialized in either compiler. You set `action.sa_handler` but all other fields remain uninitialized. Starting with gcc-7 the compiler is smart enough to notice you only initialized some fields of the struct leaving other uninitialized. Gcc-5 simply isn't that smart but that doesn't mean the struct was ever initialized. What you see in action.sa_flags is simply whatever garbage is left on the stack from the crt0 code before main was called.

Although technically wrong for pointers in structs the general solution to this is to memset() the struct to 0.